# Getting document text from webbrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have the following code, which is meant to simply get the document text from a website, but I can't get it to work. It seems that the document completed method (PrintDocument) is never being called. The console just opens and sits there, with nothing ever being printed to the screen.

```
    class BrowserControl
{
    public void PrintHelpPage()
    { 
        WebBrowser webBrowserForPrinting = new WebBrowser();

        webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted +=
            new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(PrintDocument);

        webBrowserForPrinting.Url = new Uri("http://www.fooweb.com");
    }

    public void PrintDocument(object sender,
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Print the document now that it is fully loaded.
        string test = ((WebBrowser)sender).DocumentText;

        Console.WriteLine(test);
        Console.WriteLine("DONE! ---------------------");

    }
}


    class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BrowserControl browser = new BrowserControl();

        Thread browserThread = new Thread(browser.PrintHelpPage);
        browserThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        browserThread.Start();

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are forgetting to actually navigate to the document.

There are a few things missing here but the key ones are calling `.Navigate()` instead of `.Url`, and to keep the event pipeline going by using `Application.DoEvents()` or similar call until the document is fully loaded.

1st I would recommend using `STAThreadAttribute` in your `Main()` entry point instead of applying `ApartmentState.STA` to an individual thread. It might still work your way but in the past I've always used an attribute instead:

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BrowserControl browser = new BrowserControl();
```

Secondly, you really need to use `WebBrowser.Navigate(url)` if you want something to happen.

```
    webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted +=
        new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(PrintDocument);

    webBrowserForPrinting.Navigate("http://www.fooweb.com");
}
```

Thirdly, for the document to load and `DocumentCompleted` handler to execute you need to run an event pipeline as follows:

```
    webBrowserForPrinting.Navigate("http://www.fooweb.com");

    while(webBrowserForPrinting.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) 
    {
        Application.DoEvents()
    }
 }
```

Also, dont forget to kick off the action:

```
class Program
{
  [STAThread]
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    BrowserControl browser = new BrowserControl();
    browser.PrintHelpPage();

    Console.ReadKey();

  }
}
```

Hope this is useful. Cherio.

Comment: great. this is helpful. however, when running this i receive the following error message: Unable to get the window handle for the 'WebBrowser' control. Windowless ActiveX controls are not supported.' From reading other answers it seems like I somehow need to invoke a control?

Comment: You can use WebBrowser control without a window. I use it on [triflejs.org](http://triflejs.org/) as a headless IE browser. I think you were just missing a call to `browser.PrintHelpPage()`